# Check if Method is being ran for the first time. C#

Tags: c#, methods

I am currently Trying to learn C#, I am coming from another Language so learning C# has been a breeze (so far). However, I was creating a console application in which the user enters a username and password then they get logged in. When they are logged in, I simply ask them for what they want and they type in their request. Now the thing is, whenever they pass the if/else if/else statements, I move them to a new method that greets them with a "Hello, welcome, Please enter a request". after they put in the request, I want the console to only say "Please enter a request". Thus I want to check if the method is being ran for the first time. Any ideas on how to do it.

Comment: The first thing you should do is show us your code! There are a million ways to do what you want, so seeing your code would let us know which way would suit you best.

Answer (score 3):

I think this should do it

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static bool hasRun = false;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GreetUser();// first call
            GreetUser();// second call
        }
        private static void GreetUser()
        {
            var message = "Hello, welcome. Please enter a request: ";
            // could be refactored to
            if (hasRun)
            {
                message = "Please enter a request: ";
            }
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            var requestText = Console.ReadLine();
            hasRun = true;
        }
    }
}
```

first call to `GreetUser()` will be:

> Hello, welcome. Please enter a request:

second and subsequent calls to `GreetUser()` will be:

> Please enter a request:

**EDIT:**
Oh one thing I forgot is that you could further refactor the message using ternary operator to this:

```
private static void GreetUser()
{
    var message = (!hasRun ? "Hello, welcome. " : string.Empty) + "Please enter a request: ";
    Console.WriteLine(message);
    var requestText = Console.ReadLine();
    hasRun = true;
}
```

Turns 4 lines of code into 1